# How to specify how values are to be formatted in HTML when using Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

Let's say I have an object

```
var context = {
    subject: "Hello", 
    from: "Joe", 
    date:"2017-03-09T16:34:20Z", 
    message: "Test message", 
    msg_size: 1243, 
    tags: ['URGENT']
};
```

Is there a way to define how each object type should be rendered **in the HTML template itself**? Let's say in one place I want the date to be formatted as "Mar 9, 2017" and another place I want the date to say "1 day ago" (i.e. using Moment.js), or I want a number rendered with a fixed number of decimals.

Or is the only way to apply formatting of values by first converting the context values to strings then executing the template? It would be convenient to specify how data is to be formatted in the HTML itself.

Comment: You can add your own custom handlebar helper methods to modify the dates in the html.  http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a JSFiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/ohL5bjqb/

`Goontracker` was right about using helpers. Here's the JS:

```
var context = {
  subject: "Hello",
  from: "Joe",
  date: "2017-03-09T16:34:20Z",
  message: "Test message",
  msg_size: 1243,
  tags: ['URGENT']
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('parsedDate', function(person) {
  return moment(context.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('daysAgo', function(person) {
  var now = moment(new Date()); //todays date
  var end = moment(context.date); // another date
  var duration = moment.duration(now.diff(end));
  var days = duration.asDays();
  return Math.round(days);
});

var source = $("#some-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$('body').append(template(context));
```

And the HTML:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>Subject: {{subject}}</div>
  <div>From: {{from}}</div>
  <div>Message: {{message}}</div>
  <div>Date: {{date}}</div>
  <div>Parsed Date: {{parsedDate}}</div>
  <div>Days Ago: {{daysAgo}}</div>
</script>
```

And the output:

```
Subject: Hello
From: Joe
Message: Test message
Date: 2017-03-09T16:34:20Z
Parsed Date: 03/09/2017
Days Ago: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for clear example! After researching this a bit, I should also add that it is possible to pass in parameters (this is called [_literals_](http://handlebarsjs.com/#literals) in Handlebars parlance). For example a 'format' parameter could be passed in as well covering both cases: {{parseDate format="date"}} and {{parseDate format="daysAgo"}}. In the helper code one would check for person.hash.format == "daysAgo" or person.hash.format == "date" to decide what to return. Would be possible to build a single helper to handle multiple formats of a particular data type.

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to put formatters in the template itself,
what you are looking for is Handlebars.registerHelper
i.e. before the template is rendered

```
handlebars.RegisterHelper("fooIze", function(){
  return "foo";
});
```

then in your template
{fooIze "ANYTHING"}
will render as

```
foo
```

like this
http://jaskokoyn.com/2013/08/08/custom-helpers-handlebars-js-tutorial/